# What does the "sudo apt-get install gnome-*" command?

Tags: gnome

I am wondering what sudo apt-get install gnome-* does? What does it install?

Comment: Installs all available packages that starts with `gnome-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-s` option of apt to simulate the results of an `apt install` command without actually installing anything.

Example:

```
apt install -s gnome-*
```

Because you are not actually installing anything you don't need to preface a simulated command with sudo in order to run it.

```
-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
      No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on
      the current system state but do not actually change the system.
      Simulations can also be executed by non-root users which might not 
      have read access to all apt configuration distorting the simulation. 
      A notice expressing this warning is also shown by default for 
      non-root users.
```

The `-s` option of apt can be applied to any apt command such as update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, install, remove, purge, autoremove, etc.

Example:

```
$ apt -s autoremove
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The `-s` option of apt is also useful after upgrading Ubuntu to a newer release in order to show the results of removing a package which seems to be no longer useful without actually removing that package.

Comment: Thank you. Really useful.